# Can't sign up for Azure - "We were unable to verify your account"

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, google-voice

Anyone else have this problem?

**I cannot sign up for an Azure account.**

On the registration page, it asks for your phone number and wants to confirm it by sending a text or calling you.  I only have a Google Voice number, and I always get

```
We were unable to verify your account
```

No matter if I choose text or call.  There is no way around it.  Any help?

**EDIT:** Other posts have indicated it's a problem when your country isn't listed, but that is not the case here (I'm in the U.S.).  Those posts suggest calling "your local Microsoft branch" but how do I find that?

[image: Here's a screenshot]
.

Comment: This is an Azure signup issue, unrelated to programming. You should try contacting billing support. Unfortunately this question doesn't fit on StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, although I agree with David that this is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow, I was running into the same thing a few minutes ago when trying to verify a US number, so I was happy to hear I wasn't the only one.

Comment: @Taytay So, who do we call at Microsoft to get manually verified? And re: appropriateness for StackOverflow, I also agree, but as I couldn't find much about this issue anywhere, I thought this would help bring it to light -- it's a major roadblock for a developer like me who is trying to sign up so I can create a project and possibly become a paying customer!

Comment: Perhaps [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1fd37e1-3278-4654-9f8d-74076a7e31b2/azure-mobile-service-free-trial-account-verification-does-not-work) on technet will help.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks, I had found that thread during my initial research. I guess I will have to call Microsoft myself... disappointing.

Comment: I called their US Number as specified here: http://support.microsoft.com/gp/customer-service-phone-numbers?wa=wsignin1.0.  I got transferred a couple of times, but they had me fixed up within a few hours.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After reading the comments above, and calling Microsoft myself, I was told the verification process **does not support Google Voice or Skype phone numbers**.

The person I spoke with on the pre-sales department of Azure said he could not manually create an account for me or validate my Google Voice number, despite me sending him this question on StackOverflow showing that others had been successful in calling Microsoft as I had.

My solution was to use a friend's number and have him send me the verification code he received.  However, it must be within the Azure signup's session timeout period or the code is no good.

I really hope someone at Microsoft sees this and corrects it for future customers.

Comment: I actually have been having the same issue but I'm not using a google number. I'm using my cell phone number but it still isn't working for me. So it seems their system has more issues than just google voice numbers

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to throw in a answer for Republic Wireless users who are having this problem.
I know this doesn't pertain specifically to Republic Wireless, but this is for those users, and should perhaps prove helpful, since this is the 1st result from Google on the error message.

Republic Wireless is a VoIP company, but they still use an underlying sprint phone number to handle calls/texts when you are not under WiFi, here is how to access your underlying phone number so you can get past the Windows Azure registration verification:

1. Open the Phone app (the standard dialer that comes with the phone).
2. Dial ##786#.
3. The number shown for Mobile Number is your Sprint number.
4. Hit the Back or Home button to dismiss the information screen.

https://community.republicwireless.com/people/carlh/blog/2013/11/20/moto-x-how-to-find-out-your-phones-sprint-number

Comment: The above instructions work for the Moto X. For the older Defy XT, follow the instructions here: [https://community.republicwireless.com/people/carlh/blog/2013/06/28/defy-xt-how-to-find-out-your-phones-sprint-number]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact same error. After trying different solutions, i decided to change my browser from Google Chrome to Microsoft Edge - and i was able to verify my account thereafter